# Capitalization Rules for Ellipses

Tags: capitalization, ellipses, sentence-fragments

when you have ellipses in a text such as a novel, I was wondering what the capitalization rules are for the first word after the ellipsis. My understanding, which is not based on anything other than guesswork, is that when it is a fragment of a sentence after the ellipsis, you do not capitalize the first word after the ellipsis. But if it is a full sentence after the ellipsis, you do capitalize the first word after the ellipsis.

For example:

1. And on and on it went...until finally stopping.
2. And on and on it went...Then one day, love found him.

Is this true? I assume the same rules applies to quotations too, correct? Thank you.

Comment: According to MLA rules in that answer, then yes what I said is correct. But I want to confirm this is the true for novels too. Thank you.

Comment: You capitalize the beginning of a sentence and proper nouns. The ellipsis doesn't change this rule.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But even in a quote, is this true? For example: Fred slowly said, "Give it to me now, or else...you'll die." Or: Fred slowly said, "Give it to me now, or else...You'll die." The second one looks funny to me.

Comment: "You'll die" isn't the beginning of a sentence if it follows "or else".

Comment: Okay, got it. Then: Fred slowly said, "Give it to me now, or else you'll die...you hear me?" is incorrect. Whereas: Fred slowly said, "Give it to me now, or else you'll die...You hear me?" is correct. Thank you.

Comment: I believe 4 dots finish a sentence, and 3 dots don't.  Then the capitalization would depend on the number of dots.

Comment: Why do you think punctuation in novels would be any different?

Comment: @aparente Yes, << And on and on it went....Then one day, love found him.>> is fine.

Comment: @KateBunting Punctuation rules in novels can be different from APA and MLA grammar rules, based on the novels I've read versus university papers I've read. E.g., whether to put a comma before 'and' in a list of items (1, 2, and 3, versus 1, 2 and 3...the latter seems to be more common in novels, I've noticed). You seem more of an expert on grammar than me.

Comment: That is the [Oxford comma](https://www.lexico.com/explore/what-is-the-oxford-comma). Its use depends on the writer's or publisher's choice, and has nothing to do with whether the text is fiction or not.

Comment: @KateBunting Hi Ms. Bunting, I have written 3 books, and worked with 2 different editors. But they are not as knowledgeable about grammar as you are. Is there is any way I can pay you to have a Zoom or Skype call with me just to ask you several specific questions while showing you on the call, the in-text punctuation? Please, I will compensate you generously.